# What is the proper term for a smooth scrolling mouse (instead of line-by-line)?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

I am trying to shop for a mouse which offers scrolling similar to what I experience on my trackpad (essentially pixel-by-pixel scrolling). This is much smoother and nicer, compared with the line-by-line scrolling that mice typically offer.

However, it is hard to search for a mouse which offers this functionality because I don't know what terms to use. Is there a term? Or is it really just "smooth scrolling"?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

There is a fundamental difference because of the technology behind it.

By tradition, a mouse scrolls a number of lines or a page, depending on what setting is used. Some mouse have the ability to use a smooth scrolling feature which will make it seem like a smooth scroll, but still the amount of lines are taken into effect, which can be easily noticed in programs such as Excel.

A trackpad works quite differently and has overcome the problem with scrolling. This is mostly a design choice.

With extensive testing, they found out that scrolling a wheel to control scrolling by lines was easily achieved and feeled natural to scroll text with least effort.

With gesture scrolling on a trackpad, it is far easier to control how much you want to scroll.

For that reason, to my knowledge there isn't a mouse that has the option to do a pixel by pixel scrolling. It would be very tedious anyway.

Due to there not being any mouse, I don't think there is a term for this either.

My recommendation would be to buy a trackpad instead to replace the mouse, or use in conjuncture with a mouse.

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't literally mean pixel-by-pixel. I meant not controlled by the number of lines because it seems jerkier. That said, with further testing I've found that scrolling with my existing mouse is smooth enough on Windows. It's just really jerky on OSX Sierra. I'm starting to think it might be an OSX issue: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253784/logitech-mouse-scrolling-weird-after-sierra-update-soggy-inertia-effect-in-nati

Comment: I guess another way to phrase my question is, "how is the scrolling resolution of a mouse specified." Some gaming mice have a DPI specification for how sensitive the overall mouse is to movements on a mousepad, but there doesn't seem to be a similar specification for scrolling wheels.

Comment: Ah, Thats a big difference. A magic mouse will definitely have no scrolling issues. Or any other apple product for that matter.

Comment: Also, there is one mouse that I know might be what you're looking for. The Logitech MX Air. It doesn't has a scroll wheel, but a trackpad in its location. The scrolling is artificial and feels the same as a trackpad. But its an expensive mouse for just scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any general or standardized term existing in any input device or PS2 or USB standards committees. But "Free Scroll" tends to be used often. I know that Logitech has a technology they call "Hyper-scroll" and I tend to like Logitech as I have purchased at least 6 different ones over the years and have never had a single issue with any of them seaming to be very well designed, durable and long lasting. I would assume that this would be a vendor technology term that would vary by manufacturer. If you are talking about the clicking of the scroll wheel (indexing) then Logitech's "Hyper-scroll" is supposed to be smooth without the clicking. The one I am using at the moment is the MX550 and is indexes but the clicking is very subtle. But one thing that mice have in common is that when you press the scroll wheel and get the circle with the up and down arrows, it scrolls more smoothly as you move the physical mouse as it is dependent on optical and not the wheel. But as LPChip pointed out, a trackpad and a mouse with a scroll wheel are two different hardware technologies. You would think in terms of how the pc see them electronically that would be the same and act the same but not necessarily.

I would look for an 'Optical' mouse as they are the most smooth, efficient and foolproof. They represent the current trend as probably 75-80 of the mice or "meeces" ( is there a correct term for pc mouse plural) on the market are 'Optical. There are some laser mice still being sold but I have never encountered one that is consistently smooth and reliable on a variety of surfaces. and are a dying technology in terms of mice. I would also look for on with the highest DPI setting like 120dpi minimum.

Another note, which DOES NOT sound like an issue (you mentioned your trachpad scrolls smoothly on this system) you have and may help others, refresh rate of the pc display can give the illusion that it is not scrolling smoothly. But this is usually only the case if the display setting are not set correctly or the system is older and is not usually the issue with more modern pc manufactured in the last 7 years even if on-board graphics processing is used.